# Can canonical tags on filter pages direct search engines to the main categories?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, technical-seo

I'm working on a job board. The filters on the job board spawn around a million different category pages. I'm wondering if the best solution for potentially thin and/or duplicated pages is to use the canonical tag to point search engines in the direction of the main (and most important) categories?

Is there a better solution to ensure the important pages get crawled, and should we perhaps deindex less important pages is another option I'm considering.